# Merge on key and keep values of first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df1
key value
A 1
B 2
C 2
D 3

df2
key value
C 3
D 3
E 5
F 7
```

I would like to merge this dataframes by their key and get a dataframe which looks like this one. So, I want to get only one column (no new column with suffixes) and remove the value of df2 if the values do not fit together.

```
df_merged
key value
A 1
B 2
C 2
D 3
E 5
F 7
```

How can I do this? Should I rather take `join` or `concatenate`? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) by column `key`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates('key')
print (df)
  key  value
0   A      1
1   B      2
2   C      2
3   D      3
6   E      5
7   F      7
```

Comment: @U11-Forward - There is daily limit? I dont know it.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to @jezrael's answer, you could also use `groupby` with `first`:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True).groupby('key', as_index=False).first()
  key  value
0   A      1
1   B      2
2   C      2
3   D      3
4   E      5
5   F      7
>>>
```